# how to increment counter by one when status changes

Tags: c#, timer, counter

i need to show a counter .it will increase by one when status changes.if status changes from true to false it will be increased by one but only once then on next false it will again increment . my problem is that i am using timer so if my status remains false for 1 min counter will show 60 as its increasing by one . i just need to increment only once ..e.g if it changes to true to false it will increment by one .then wait if status goes back to true and then again false then it should increment by one otherwise the counter will be just one . help me in that please

```
void opc_status()
    {

        Int32 InRuntimeNumber = 0;

        InRuntimeNumber = ModuleNetworkNode.OPCSystemsComponent1.InRuntime("192.168.1.2");

        if (InRuntimeNumber == -1)
        {

            textBox.Text= "Service not reached";


        }

        else if (InRuntimeNumber == 1)
        {

            textBox.Text = "Active";

        }

        else
        {

            textBox.Text = "Stopped";
            //rectangle_opc.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 226, 77));
        }


 public Boolean Status

    {
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_status != value)
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Open();
                }
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO Report (Date,Time, Event, [Type of Alarm]) VALUES ('" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString() + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("t") + "','" + textBox.Text + "','" + "opc" + "')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                counterlabel.Content = counter++;

            }

            _status = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way (without seeing code) is to use a property which has a side-effect (i know, not an awesome solution) which would increment the counter for you.

```
public class foo{
    private bool bar;
    private int counter;

    private bool Bar { 
        get{
         return bar;
        } 
        set{
            if(bar != value && bar){
                counter++;
            }
            bar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

edit: updated per requirements. It should be noted that this is not a great way of doing this, but rather a method to modify the `bar` property would be better.

Also, there are a number of issues with the code provided in the question:

- SQL injection vulnerability
- side effect of modifying a property causing a record to be written to a database.
- it would be better to use the SQL `GETDATE()` or `GETUTCDATE()` function to get the date and time rather than sending that from the app.

Comment: thank u . i added the code based on these i have to increment the counter

Comment: it will only increment if its stopped or service nit reached . i am using that function in timer .which will continuously checking the status if its stopped or active .

Comment: using your code will increment on both .e.g if it goes from true to false or false to true ..

Comment: @RumarAbbasi I updated the answer with commentary and adjusted code. Ideally if you have even semi-complex conditional logic, it's a good idea to create a Karnaugh map of what you're trying to accomplish and using that to inform you conditional logic.

Comment: i am not asking about sql bro . ijust want to show disconnection count..if opc will return stopped or not service not reached it should increment the value by one .i am using timer which is continously checking the status of opc ..